# Is pull up resistor mandatory for I2C?

Tags: i2c

I removed pull up resistors in this schematic. I am using a Zedboard (FPGA) as the controller while the touch screen (FT5316) as the peripheral.

[image]

Here is the waveform I got from my oscilloscope:

[image]

The ack bit is working perfectly. Why is SDA rising so slowly?

[image]

This JD3_N is conneted to W5 on Zynq 2020. However, JD3_N is on pmod JD1 which is differential PMOD. Does this affect this SDA?

Comment: The I2C spec requires a pullup - is the Zedboard's output pin configured to use a pullup?

Comment: Pullups are mandatory - they may be hidden inside of devices.

Comment: @nanofarad output pin is used as inout in vhdl. I set it to high-z when it's reading

Comment: Can I ask what's the purpose is of your question. The I2C spec' states to always use pull-up resistors (or resistances). What's the reason for wanting to get explanations for a situation that must be designed out?

Comment: @TonyM I just want to know what's the reason behind my strange oscilloscope wave

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The I2C spec requires a pullup, and the bus seems to be malfunctioning in your scope trace. It's driven low, but is having trouble rising to a high level.

If you don't want an external pullup, you'll need to configure a device to use its internal pullup. For example, if the bus is connected to PL pins on the Zynq FPGA, you could add an FPGA constraint to enable the pullup on those pins. Simply setting INOUT and keeping it HIGHZ when reading (as you describe in your comment) is insufficient.

A sample XDC constraint (from memory, so may be approximate):

```
set_property PULLUP true [get_ports sda_port_or_whatever_its_called]
```

A side note - Looking closer at your waveform, it seems that the clock is being driven high by the FPGA itself, because it rises quickly even with the missing pull-up. This suggests that you may run into an issue when using specific peripherals that may need to stretch the clock. If you know for a fact that your peripherals don't need to do this, you can disregard it.

If you want to handle this case, the right way to handle clock stretching is to drive the clock low, but let the clock get pulled high with the pullup while tristating when you want the clock to go high. If a peripheral needs more time to process data, *it will hold the clock low against the pullup* - you need to detect this and wait until the peripheral releases SCL and it gets pulled back to HIGH.

Comment: Do you mean I also have to set SCL as inout in FPGA?

Comment: Actually, the I2C standard says that I2C targets can hold SCL for clock stretching. However, the majority of I2C target ICs sold by volume don't use clock stretching. You'd find many/most I2C buses out there don't require the bus master to support SCL stretching. So I don't think your the statement on clock stretching, and how imperative it is that masters support it, is a fair reflection of it all to readers new to I2C, even if it's literally true - could be written better.

Comment: @TonyM The SDA rising slowly could be due to SCL stretching?

Comment: @kile, no, that's not at all what I'm saying - I wrote a comment to nanofarad.

Comment: @TonyM In my dialect of English, the wording "may run into an issue with [specific category of peripherals]" under "a side note" is neither an imperative nor reads as one to me - in fact, a side note and a paragraph of explanation is probably an understatement for the number of hours I individually lost to this one annoying edge case when I didn't understand it, found little documentation on it, etc. I can certainly add more qualifiers, but in the end, the initiator allowing the target to hold the bus *is* part of the spec.

Comment: @kile To be fully spec-compliant and work with every I2C device out there, yes, you would. If you know that your device (FT5316) will never need to stretch the clock (either because you have a low enough frequency, or because the device never stretches the clock by design) then you can still drive the clock the way you have it.

Comment: @nanofarad I did exactly what you suggested to avoid clock stretching . But  now I didn't receive any ack from slave.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/688298/fpga-scl-of-i2c-doesnt-oscillate-and-its-in-reading-mode

Answer (score 4):

You are doing I2C wrong.

Yes pull-up is mandatory. And the IO must not be push-pull output but open-drain output.

The pins are not supposed to be push-pull outputs what you seem to be doing, and that's why there must be a pull-up resistor which you removed.

What I2C is supposed to be is just pulled up by resistors and pulled down by devices.

At most, under specific conditions that no slave ever drives the clock pin low, you can use the clock as push-pull output, but you are still not supposed to do that.

So because you removed pull-ups, the bus will not be pulled high by anything except maybe weak internal pull-ups or leakage current, as all devices on bus have SDA as input. So that is why SDA rises slowly.

Comment: I added pull up resistor now. But now I didn't receive any ack from slave.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/688298/fpga-scl-of-i2c-doesnt-oscillate-and-its-in-reading-mode