# FPGA - SCL of I2C is always high when it's in reading mode

Tags: i2c

I have previously posted I2C([Is pull up resistor mandatory for I2C?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/688044/is-pull-up-resistor-mandatory-for-i2c)). But now I use an internal pull-up resistor from FPGA as @nanofarad suggested. I am using a Zedboard (FPGA) as the controller while the touch screen (FT5316) (https://files.waveshare.com/upload/0/08/Application-Note-for-CTPM.pdf) (https://files.waveshare.com/upload/9/9c/FT5x06.pdf) as the peripheral.

Now this time I use SCL as **inout signal** in VHDL in order to avoid clock stretching. And I use an internal pull-up resistor for SCL from FPGA. As for SDA, I use an external pull-up resistor.

Why does SCL not oscillate?

[image]

[image]

Update. the notation of the first picture is wrong. Here is the correct version.

Folks don't understand what I am doing here because I only posted a snippet of the waveform. The following is data I send to the slave.

```
b"0111_0000", -- 38 slave address (write)
b"0000_0000", -- 00 register address
b"1000_1010", -- 8A data
b"0000_0101", -- 05 data
b"0111_0001", -- 38 slave address (read)
b"1010_1011", -- AB register address
b"0111_0001", -- 38 slave address (read)
b"0000_0000", -- 00 register address
```

[image]

Update for Clock Stretching.

The following is a Modelsim simulation of clock stretching (SCL).
[image]

Comment: What are the two screenshots?

Comment: @TimWilliams I just want people to know SCL is not working as expected from picture I posted.

Comment: It's pretty clear in the second picture that the slave did not ACK the first transfer, so naturally, the I2C controller aborted the transaction.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes, why did the slave not ack? What should I do?

Comment: For read cycles, you still need to use the slave address, not the "register address" as the first byte of the transaction. I found [this datasheet](https://www.buydisplay.com/download/ic/FT5316.pdf), but it doesn't go into any detail about how the register access is supposed to work.

Comment: @DaveTweed I used the registered address at the beginning

Comment: Ah. When doing a read cycle, you do NOT send the register address a second time. The second byte of the transaction is the data being returned by the slave, and since the master did not ACK it (since it was transmitting), everything came to a stop.

Comment: SCL is going to stay high unless you drive it low. The process behind avoiding clock stretching is: (1) you drive the bus low for the low period and (2) you let it float high. If the chip needs to stretch the clock, it will force the bus to *stay* low. If the bus goes back to high, the chip is ready and you can then proceed with the next clock cycle when you're ready - you, as the initiator, will drive it low again. Or, if you know this device doesn't need clock stretching, you can simply drive it at a fixed rate. I'm not sure about the ACKs themselves, will need to look later.

Comment: @nanofarad Do you mean SCL will not oscillate (high) when it's in reading mode ( read from slave)?

Comment: @DaveTweed I think you misunderstand what I mean. I will post the the whole data I send to the slave.
`
    b"0111_0000", -- 38 slave address (write)
    b"0000_0000", -- 00 register address
    b"1000_1010", -- 8A data
    b"0000_0101", -- 05 data
    b"0111_0001", -- 38 slave address (read)
    b"1010_1011", -- AB register address
    b"0111_0001", -- 38 slave address (read)
    b"0000_0000", -- 00 register address
`

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. You should NOT send a register address following a "slave address (read)" -- that isn't how I2C works. All bytes following a slave address with the "read" bit set are transferred from slave to master.

Comment: @kile When considering clock stretching, SCL needs to be a collaboration between the initiator and the peripheral. You, on the zedboard, are responsible for oscillating SCL by driving it low each cycle. You, on the zedboard, then let it float back to high (unless the peripheral stretches the clock), after which you can do the next clock cycle. If the clock is stuck low, the peripheral needs more time. If the clock is stuck high, then it means that you're failing to drive it. The peripheral isn't going to start the next clock cycle for you, only stretch the current clock cycle.

Comment: What do you mean float? Is it Z (High impedance mode) for FPGA? Does clock stretching only apply to read mode from slave?

Comment: @kile Float is the exact same thing as high-impedance mode. Clock stretching can apply to both read or write mode. You might be overcomplicating the situation or misunderstanding a core principle of open-drain buses here. The clock cycle should be fairly simple. You drive the clock low to create a falling edge. A short time later, you stop driving it low and let it float. Did it rise back up? If so, good, when you're ready start the next cycle and drive it low again. If not, wait for the peripheral to release the clock line. Then you're ready to start the next cycle.

Comment: @nanofarad I have uploaded a updated ModelSim simulation of my code for this. Please  take a look if you have time.

Comment: So where did you get the code for this I2C master, anyway? It is clearly non-standard -- actively driving SCL and SDA both high and low, and tristating them both at the same time for the ACK bit. It's a wonder that it works at all!

Comment: @DaveTweed Which code do you mean? Do you mean Modesim Simulation pic?

Comment: The VHDL that you mentioned.

Comment: @DaveTweed But I haven't post any vhdl code yet!

Comment: I know, and I'm not even necessarily asking to see it. I just want to know where it came from. Is it something you wrote?

Comment: Yes, I write my own vhdl code.

Answer (score 2):

The buses are still push-pull on FPGA.

It can be seen from the spikes on the rising edges.

The slave chip tries to send an ACK and pull bus low, but the FPGA prevents it by pushing bus high. That is evident from the small dips in the bus high state, as both chips drive the bus to different states and FPGA is way stronger than your slave chip.

Also, pull-ups are usually external, because you can select how strong it is based on your needs. Using internal pull-ups may not work, as they are generally weak and allow only slower bus clock than what would be possible with external pull-ups.

As for the actual question why does not the SCL oscillate, it doesn't oscillate by itself, it's the  job of the FPGA as master to clock data out of slave. You can refer to I2C standard or application notes for that.

Comment: Could you please point out those dips in the picture? I don't understand what dips you mean

Comment: @kile The points where SDA is 3.0V instead of 3.3V.

Comment: It's not the job of FPGA as master when it's reading. It's the job of the slave when it's reading

Comment: @kile I already said it isn't the job of slave but master, and that's why your design does not work. I did not even imagine you thought it is the job of the slave. Most slaves don't even have clock outputs so how could they.

Comment: Well, one of the features of I2C is "clock stretching", so it's actually a collaboration between initiator and responder.  (That's why the initiator shall use open-drain with a weak pull-up, not push-pull driver)  Many responder devices never drive (stretch) the clock, allowing the initiator to control it fully.  Perhaps more fundamental though is that there is no change in direction on CLK between read and write as there is for SDA.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sure, clock stretching is a feature of I2C. Most slave ICs don't utilize that feature. If no slave in a design uses that feature, there is no need for the master to support it either. And there is no change in direction on SDA either. A chip pulls it low when it needs to transmit low and does not pull low when high is transmitted.

Comment: It would be nice to give a reason for the downvote. Otherwise I can't fix my answer, or prove that it is correct already.

Comment: I finally see what you're saying -- that the FPGA is actively driving both SDL and SDA high and low, rather than relying on the pullups. I agree with your interpretation of the waveforms, but that doesn't prevent the slave from driving ACK when the FPGA finally does tristate SDA, and it doesn't explain the failure on read operations. The real root cause is that the OP is trying to transmit a register address on read cycles, which is both a violation of I2C protocol in general, and the protocol documented in the OP's application note specifically.

Comment: @DaveTweed Sure, those are higher level logical data transmission protocol problems. The lower level problems in the electrical physical interface just prevent even the higher level problems. Such as the FPGA must clock out data from the sensor, wires must be driven open-drain, pull-up resistors present, and the touch screen can be interpreted to stretch clock which is uncommon (unless MCU based implementation).